# Running a pre-indexer script in Sphinx to copy data from one DB to another

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to index a few tables on a Postgres DB. It seems that Sphinx has a pre-index query that you can execute:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-sql-query-pre

Can this be used to bulk copy-insert data from another DB over a DB link into the DB that I'm indexing?

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db2', 'SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 10') AS t1(id integer, name varchar, address varchar);
```

Most of the examples I can see are used for settings session parameters so I'm sort of doubtful.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, `sql_query_pre` can be used to do *anything* that SQL can do with your data.